# Edit Event bar SharePoint 2016 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am wanting to modify the way events appear on a monthly calendar.  There are many events that we schedule that start late in the evening and do not finish until early the next morning.  Currently, these events appear as two events.  The first day from start time to 12:00am and the second day from 12:00am to end time.

What I have found so far is that any event less than 24 hours appears this way.    The 4 hour event is a typical time frame for our maintenance events, but we want it to show actual start and end times similar to the 24 hour event.  How can I modify this to fit my needs?

[image: How the calendar currently looks]